# Is there a meaningful generalization of topology?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, limits-colimits

A topology T is a collection of subsets of some set where T is closed under arbitrary union and finite intersection. Do we get a meaningful generalization if instead of union and intersection, we choose other kind of constructions in the category of sets (maybe some limits, some colimits or hom-sets) such that T is closed under these constructions? For example, sigma algebras may be considered in this way. Are there any others?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generalizing Topological Spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3919459/generalizing-topological-spaces). The key terms to look up in the existing solution is "Locales and Topoi"

Comment: Generalizing in a different way (specifically, generalizing the Kuratowski closure operator properties), see my lengthy answer-essay to [this mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/342205/15780).